# To find minimum and maximum value from a given array using divide and conquer algorithm

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
static int min,max=0,arrr[100],mid,n;
minmax(int arr[],int low,int high)
{int i;
    if(high-low==1)//for n==2
    {
        if(arr[low]<arr[high])
        {
        min=arr[low];
        max=arr[high];
        arrr[0]=min;
        arrr[1]=max;
        }
        else
        {
            min=arr[high];
            max=arr[low];
            arrr[0]=min;
            arrr[1]=max;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    if(n==1)//n==1
    {
        arrr[0]=arr[high];
        arrr[1]=arr[high];
        return 0;
    }
    mid=low+high/2;
    if(high-low>1)
    {
        mid=low+high/2;
        minmax(arr,low,mid);
        minmax(arr,mid+1,high);
       
    }
}
int main()
{
    int i,j,sum=0,low,high;
    printf("Enter the number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int arr[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the element %d: ",i);
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    } 
    low=0;//starting value of array
    high=n-1;//final value 
    minmax(arr,low,high);
    printf("\n\nMinimum element %d \n\nMaximum element %d ",arrr[0],arrr[1]);
    
}
```

I'm getting the right answers for the first two cases i.e, when n equals 1 and n equals 2. But for the third case when n is greater than 2,I'm getting the first two values of the input as minimum and maximum. The arrr is the output array that stores the minimum and the maximum value.

Comment: Isn't divide and conquer more of a strategy in approaching problems and not a real algorithm?

Comment: You have not arbitrated between the result of each half of the array. Whatever you find with the first recursive call `minmax(arr,low,mid);` is overwritten by the second call `minmax(arr,mid+1,high);`

Comment: You're also missing parens in your calculation of `mid`: `mid = (low + high) / 2;`.

Comment: .. or avoid `int` overflow with `mid=low+(high-low)/2;`

Comment: This is a perfect example of how useful a debugger can be to solve logic errors. Step through your code in the debugger so that you can trace the flow of execution and monitor the value of variables. If you haven't learned how to use a debugger yet, now is a great time to start doing so.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm just a beginner and haven't learned to use a debugger, will try to learn.